# QWidget background-image fit

Tags: qt, background-image, qwidget

I'm working with Qt 4.7 , I set a QWidget's background-image CSS an image from my qrc.

The problem is the image is High res , and only the upper left part of it is showing , I can't get it to scale down to fit. In CSS3 I saw a "background-size : contain" property but I fear it doesn't work in Qt 4.7.

Couldn't find a way to make the image fit the window. Any ideas ? 
I don't mind doing it programmatically .

Thanks

**Solved:** http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Archived:Load,_Resize_image_and_set_background_image_in_Qt_application/widget

Comment: This may be a little dated but using Qt 5.7, adding `QWidget::paintEvent(e);` at the end of my paintEvent function crashed my program and was not necessary.

Comment: The link is dead. I wish you added the solution here as an answer...

Answer (score 6):

If the QFrame is the same aspect ratio as the image you can use CSS on the QFrame like this:

```
QFrame
{
   border-image: url(:/images/myimage.png) 0 0 0 0 stretch stretch;
   border-width: 0px;
}
```

Comment: That stretches the image to the very edges of the border, is there a way to maintain aspect ratio?

Answer (score 5):

You can reimplement `paintEvent` :

```
void Widget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, QPixmap(":/new/prefix1/picture001.png").scaled(size()));
    QWidget::paintEvent(e);
}
```